# If $\beta=0.{a_1}^{k}{a_2}^{k}{a_3}^{k}\cdots\in\mathbb Q$, then $\alpha=0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots\in\mathbb Q$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

> **Question** : For every **even** $k\ge 4$, is the following $(\star)$ true?
>
> $$\begin{align}\text{If $\beta=0.{a_1}^{k}{a_2}^{k}{a_3}^{k}\cdots\in\mathbb Q$, then $\alpha=0.a_1a_2a_3\cdots\in\mathbb Q$.}\qquad(\star)\end{align}$$
>
> Here, $a_i$ is the $i$-th decimal place of $\alpha$.

**Example** : For $k=2,\alpha=0.12345,$ we have $\beta=0.1491625.$

**Motivation** : I've been able to prove that the answer is **NO** for $k=2$, and that the answer is **YES** for every **odd** $k\ge 3$. The answer seems YES for **any** $k\ge 3$, but I'm facing difficulty for treating every even $k$ in general. Can anyone help?

**Remark** : One of the counterexamples for $k=2$ is $\alpha=0.237237723777237777\cdots$. This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585537/if-beta-0-a-1ka-2ka-3k-cdots-in-mathbb-q-then-alpha-0-a-1a) without receiving any answers.

Comment: Maybe you can say a little more about the motivation for this question? -- E.g. why you think this is interesting, or what you could use it for.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Well, I thought $(\star)$ must be true for any $k\ge 2$, so I was a bit surprised to get a counterexample for $k=2$. The main reason why I think this is interesting might be that even though the conjecture must be true, proving that is not very easy. I love this kind of questions. Also, I don't know what we could use it for. In my opinion, we don't always need it though there may be anything useful that I don't notice.

Comment: Can you describe your proof for odd $k$?

Comment: @user43383: If $k$ is odd, then the one's digit of $1^k ,2^k ,\cdots,9^k$ are different from each other. Using this fact will enable you to prove what you desire.

Comment: Note that it is base dependent. In base $3$, we still have the property that the last digit is preserved when the number is taken to an odd power, but yet it fails for the even powers $2$ and $8$. For $2$, notice that $2^2=11_3$, and for $8$, $2^8=100111_3$.